# Is there a Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for unramified cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, etale-cohomology

Similar to the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for etale cohomology ($H^p(G, H^q_{et}(X_L, \mathcal F|_{X_L})) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}_{et}(X, \mathcal F)$ for a Galois field extension $L/k$ with Galois group $G$), does there exist a Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for unramified cohomology?  If yes, how to obtain it?  If no, why does it not exist?

Comment: I believe that unramified cohomology does not have etale descent; hence there cannot exist a Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for it.